# Ubuntu Firefox 64 bit sometimes loads css incorrectly

Tags: html, css, firefox, curl

I have a web page on `127.0.0.1` that has about 10 stylesheets. It seems firefox randomly redirects the css file(s) (Not all of them) to the current page you are on. This means when accessing it via the browser instead of showing css it shows html. This file is just static .css file. This causes the css to not render and the page to look broken.

If I reset the browser by deleting history and temporary files the web site then works fine again. Also when I use curl I get the right result. Has anyone had problems like this on Firefox for Ubuntu? It seems to be a firefox issue as curl works fine and the browser eventually works when I clear the cache.

Ubuntu: `14.0.4` in parallels VM

Firefox: `31.0`

Seems to only happen on 127.0.0.1 does NOT happen on localhost. Does NOT happen in Chrome.

Steps to reproduce

1. Load page
2. Refresh page
3. Note that the styles break. If you look at server it is sending back a 304 but it seems the browser is having trouble caching the file..only one 127.0.0.1...very odd

Comment: Apache,  nginx, or what?

Comment: It is apache. I have confirmed it is a bug in firefox 31. I upgraded to firefox 33 and it didn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in Firefox 31 and upgrading to firefox 33 fixed this problem.